# Load xaml file in c#, get element with specified name, add button and save file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have XAML file with file name `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid x:Name="Content">         

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, I would like to load this file in my project in C#, get element with name *`Content`*, add `Button` and save file.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"MainWindow.xaml");
var gridElement = doc.Root.Element("Content"); // it is NULL
```

But I can't get grid element with name `Content`, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting another answer because the first one is useful but does not immediately address your requirements

The document you have given us is invalid. It does not feature a closing `Window` tag.

The reason you cannot get the grid element is that you have not provided a namespace to use. As the Grid element does not feature a namespace prefix, we can assume that it's namespace is the document's default namespace; `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`.

How do I know what the document default it? Because of line 2 in your document:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

**EDIT**

The `Element()` method takes the element's xml name - in this case you want `Grid`. You then have to check the name.

You may want to simplify your code. As this is XAML, you can make assumptions about the format. For example, window will only have one child element.

This is my test code. There are all sorts of implicit operators going on here which will make the `+` operator compile despite the types being weird. Don't worry about that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XamlLoad
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = @"<Window x:Class=""WpfApplication1.MainWindow""
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
        xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
        Title=""MainWindow"" Height=""350"" Width=""525"">
    <Grid x:Name=""Content"">


    </Grid>
</Window>";

            var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(file));
            XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
            XNamespace x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
            var gridElement = doc.Root.Elements(xmlns + "Grid").Where(p => p.Attribute(x + "Name") != null && p.Attribute(x + "Name").Value == "Content");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need something like `Element(xmlns  + "Grid").Where(e => e.Attributes.Any(a => a.value ==  "Content"));`

Comment: @user2400938 glad to hear you got it working. I used the TextReader overload of XDocument.Load so that I could put the sample file (string) and the loading code in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader` to load in your file from stream.

> **XamlReader Class**
>
> Reads XAML input and creates an object graph, using the WPF default
>   XAML reader and an associated XAML object writer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx

You have to cast the return object to the root type to use it. In this exmaple, the root element is a

```
using(var fs = new FileStream("MainWindow.xaml"))
{
    Window page = (Window)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(fs);
}
```

Comment: In the absence of an error, I can only assume this is because you are using a non-STA apartment thread to do this work? Check the inner exception of the exception that occurred. Failing that, give me something better to work with.